# Why does AllocConsole work in VS2015 but not in VS2019

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to use `AllocConsole` to redirect the output message of a WinForm project.
But now the question is that the same code works fine in VS2015 but not in VS2019.
In VS2015, the console shows up and prints the message as expected.
However, if I open this project with VS2019, the console also shows up, but the message will still be printed to the vs output window.
Any one has any idea?
The code is as below.

```
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            
            var result = AllocConsole(); 
            //It returns true here in both VS2015 and VS2019
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Application.Run(new Form1());

            FreeConsole();
        }

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private extern static bool AllocConsole();

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private extern static bool FreeConsole();
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run it outside of Visual Studio?

Comment: @RetiredNinja It works fine, the console shows up, and the message is printed to the console, no matter which version of vs I used to compile it.

Comment: @ZelgiusLiu, based on my test, I reproduced your problem. If you want the message to be shown in the console window, you could change Output type from **Windows Application** to **Console application**. Based on my test, it can show the message in the console window.